# How do these sentences sound?

Tags: grammar

How do these sentences sound?

Do these sentences sound natural to native speakers?

1. If they reopen the border, he can transport the drugs out of the country on Monday.
2. If he loses his recipe, he can’t make this dish for his guest on Friday.
3. If it rains, he can’t go fishing on Saturday.
4. If you guys leave early, I can’t take you to my favorite bar tonight.

Comment: To be [on-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, we can't just say "is this ok." Please use the "Edit" button to explain more about what you think might be wrong and why; this will give more useful answers.

Comment: Some are more awkward than others: should "If it rains, he can’t go fishing on Saturday" be "If it rains on Saturday, he can’t go fishing"? Or will rain now stop him going fishing then?